# Why socket.io won't connect?

Tags: http, socket.io

To my understanding socket.io is based on HTTP which is a standard protocol. I have my c code for HTTP server and when I type in a browser "localhost:8080" the server is working.
But when I call

```
var socket = new io.Socket('http://localhost', {port: 8080 }); 
socket.connect();
```

The c code doesn't pass the

```
accept (sock,&addr,&addrlen);
```

Please Advice.10xs,Nir

Comment: you need socket.io on the server as well - socket.io on the server will listen on a certain port that you will specify - the client needs to connect to that port.

Comment: why shouldn't any http socket will do? it is http...

Answer (score 0):

you need socket.io on the server as well - socket.io on the server will listen on a certain port that you will specify - the client needs to connect to that port.
Also, socket.io uses websockets by default (unless changed in the latest version) and then falls back on other protocols that you can configure (flash sockets/xhr etc.)

**Server side using Javascript**:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);  //8080 since you are trying to connect to that port
```

If you don't wish to use javascript on the server, I believe there are multiple ports available for socket.io in other languages.  Hope it helps

Comment: Absolutely WRONG!!!!!! Where did you get the idea that the server needs to use Socket.io also???? Please give reference...

Comment: Where does it say that it only works with socket.io in both server and client side? and server/client using socket.io does not work non-socket.io server/client?

Comment: there are lot's of socket.io not in JS, after all node on my server is JS but after all it is c. look at this:[link](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc/blob/master/SocketIO.m) it is just http

Comment: I might have erred (quite possible).  However, as I mentioned in my note - there are multiple ports available in other languages so using javascript is not required.  If you wish to write your own implementation instead of using those implementations for handling all fallbacks, then one can start from scratch.

Comment: Yep, there are many. The answer to my question is that browsers can be served with server that it's socket is init by PF_INET while socket.io must be served with AF_INET

Answer (score 0):

Try without the  `http://`

```
var socket = new io.Socket('localhost', {port: 8080 }); 
socket.connect();
```

Also, for localhost, you can use null for host

```
var socket = new io.Socket(null, {port: 8080 }); 
socket.connect();
```